# Programming language for completing an online quiz repeadetly?

Tags: scripting, ui-automation

I'm trying to complete an online multiple-choice quiz repeadetly (for a contest) and I want to automate that. Unfortunately, I don't know what programming language I should use or if i'd be better off using a simpler tool (if so, which tool?).
The program/script needs to do the following:

- control the mouse cursor (to click answers and continue)
- be able to read text from the webpage (or read it from the html file) and answer accordingly

There aren't many different questions that it needs to answer so actually finding the answers isn't difficult.

Answer (score 1):

I did a kind of task using Sahi. You can record the flows & modify script as per requirement. It is reliable among all for quick start for such small activities.

You can download it from https://sourceforge.net/projects/sahi/.